# IBM Rhapsody: Generate c++ class in implementation file

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom, rhapsody

I would like to generate a c++ class in the implementation file (.cpp) instead of the header file, in order to implement the PIMPL idiom.

For example: http://www.cppsamples.com/common-tasks/pimpl.html

How can I achieve this in IBM Rhapsody, using the inbuilt autocoder?

Comment: Put the header content to your .cpp file. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

in order to force Rhapsody to generate class to the implementation file you need to add source artifact (file) and map the class specification to it.

note: Rhapsody don't support C++11 syntax.

## steps:

1. enable view of source artifact- set property Browser::Settings::ShowSourceArtifacts = true, on the project level
2. add source artifacts - right click menu on the class->add>source artifact (do twice for both spec and impl)
3. delete from model the .h source artifact you added
4. in the .cpp source artifact open feature dialog and in the "Elements" tab, double click on the class (the nested element) and change element type from "implementation" to "specification+implementation"
5. generate code

Regards
Oded 
(Rhapsody developer)